# Install a plugin in a complex unix environment

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I've created an eclipse plugin on my local host, which works ok.

Now I've to deploy the plugin (.jar) file to some complex unix based environment which has dozens of eclipse installations.

I need to have the plugin only in one of the eclipse instances.

I tried to find all plugin/features/droping directories in system and copy to each of them my plugin. But still I cannot see it in eclipse.

I tried to

- Install New Software and Add a local archive but eclipse failed with `"no repository found"`

**Questions :**

- How can I install the jar file plugin from GUI ?
- If its not possible, how can I figure out where is the correct
  location of plugin    directory from inside eclipse GUI ?
- Otherwise how can I see if the eclipse is trying to load the .jar
  plugin at all ? (Probably some of the dependencies are failing...)

Answer (score 1):

When you tried

> Install New Software and Add a local archive but eclipse failed with "no repository found"

Did you provide the plug-in .jar directly or an update site ?
You should create an update site for it to work.

See http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html#p2deployplugin

(The drop-in solution is not reliable.)

Comment: When I wrote the question I was trying with .jar. I've already solved my problem using update site methode. Later will post a full answer. Anyway thanks for a response +1